# Typescript - conflicting method signatures in intersection type

Tags: typescript, feathersjs

I use [FeathersJS](https://feathersjs.com/) (which is awesome) but unfortunately, it's not written in TypeScript so the typings have to be written and maintained separately.

[Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/feathersjs__feathers/index.d.ts) is the typings files. In it, there's a `Service<T>` type that looks like:

```
export type Service<T> = ServiceOverloads<T> & ServiceAddons<T> & ServiceMethods<T>;
```

`ServiceOverloads<T>` looks like:

```
export interface ServiceOverloads<T> {
    create(data: Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params): Promise<T[]>;

    create(data: Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    patch(id: NullableId, data: Pick<T, keyof T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
}
```

and `ServiceMethods<T>` looks like:

```
export interface ServiceMethods<T> {
    find(params?: Params): Promise<T[] | Paginated<T>>;

    get(id: Id, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    create(data: Partial<T> | Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params): Promise<T | T[]>;

    update(id: NullableId, data: T, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    patch(id: NullableId, data: Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    remove(id: NullableId, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
}
```

As you can see, the `create` and `patch` methods should conflict because they generate the same JavaScript.

Why does the type alias `Service<T>` compile but when trying to implement it fails due to conflicting methods? If I copy the methods exactly from each interface and provide a stub implementation, that should work no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of types with function signatures corresponds to [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) those functions.  From the relevant [GitHub issue introducing intersection types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622):

> Call and Construct Signatures
>
> If `A` has a signature `F` and `B` has a signature `G`, then `A & B` has signatures `F` and `G` in that order (the order of signatures matter for purposes of overload resolution). Except for the order of signatures, the types `A & B` and `B & A` are equivalent.

In your case, `ServiceOverloads<T> & ServiceMethods<T>` is effectively

```
{
    create(data: Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params): Promise<T[]>; 
    create(data: Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
    create(data: Partial<T> | Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params): Promise<T | T[]>;

    patch(id: NullableId, data: Pick<T, keyof T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
    patch(id: NullableId, data: Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    find(params?: Params): Promise<T[] | Paginated<T>>;

    get(id: Id, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    update(id: NullableId, data: T, params?: Params): Promise<T>;

    remove(id: NullableId, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
}
```

and therefore you need to implement it where `create()` and `patch()` are overloaded methods, not single-signature methods.  Here's a sample:

```
class ServiceImpl<T> {
  create(data: Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params): Promise<T[]>; 
  create(data: Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
  create(data: Partial<T> | Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params): Promise<T | T[]>;
  create(data: Partial<T> | Array<Partial<T>>, params?: Params) : Promise<T> | Promise<T[]> {
    return null!;  // impl
  }

  patch(id: NullableId, data: Pick<T, keyof T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
  patch(id: NullableId, data: Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T>;
  patch(id: NullableId, data: Pick<T, keyof T> | Partial<T>, params?: Params): Promise<T> {
    return null!; // impl
  }

  // other methods
}

function getService<T>(): Service<T> {
  return new ServiceImpl<T>(); // okay
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That worked almost perfectly! The only thing I had to change was the last signature; I had to remove it. Other than that, that was amazing! Thanks man!